# Being asked to join Meta when already a user results in error

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, mso-mse-split

So I don't know if this has something to do with the meta switch over or if this is truly a bug in the app.
But when I tried to comment on a post in meta I got the following alert message, Image 1, asking me to join the site. When clicking join the error message, Image 2, ensued.

[image: Asked to join]
[image: Error Message]

Comment: Rats. Goodness knows we need more memers.

Comment: Thanks for the report, I'm investigating

Comment: Are you consistently getting this error, or was it a one time thing? I am unable to reproduce on my end.

Comment: @Arie it seems I cannot reproduce now, perhaps because I have since logged into the meta sites from desktop?

Comment: @ArieLitovsky: a Android user sees is seeing the same thing: [Unable to use Android app on MSE/MSO after split](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229881)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the copy, I have fixed the 'memers' typo above. That should be visible by version 0.1.50.

Regarding the actual issue: as mentioned on the answer to a [similar question for Android](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229881/unable-to-use-android-app-on-mse-mso-after-split), this is a caching issue that should fix itself by now (since the cache only lasts about 24 hours). If you still experience this issue, please report it again.