# Unable to use Android app on MSE/MSO after split

Tags: bug, android-app, mso-mse-split

On the Android app, when I click to add a comment, I'm prompted to join MSE. Clicking Join gives me an error message that I'm already a member. Further, MSE does not show in the list of sites when I create a new question.

[image]

Also, no tags are showing when I type them in to a new question on MSO, in the search results. Typing them manually and clicking Done results in them being removed, preventing me from asking a question.

[image]

Comment: Seems to be working for me

Comment: I saw this posted earlier today but can no longer find it. I suspect the problem went away for that poster..

Comment: @MBraedley how useful...

Comment: Which is why I didn't post it as an answer.  All I'm saying is that I can access MSE just fine from my phone.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: That *is* useful in narrowing down this issue. If it is not happening for everyone then that gives us more parameters.

Comment: @Martijn, you referring to this iOS one? [Being asked to join Meta when already a user results in error](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229818/being-asked-to-join-meta-when-already-a-user-results-in-error)

Comment: @mhlester: Bingo! I didn't think to look for iOS issues..

Comment: @mhlester That looks like the same thing alright! Just to add some info, I'd already been on both MSE and MSO on my PC, prior to using the app.

Answer (score 3):

This is a caching issue on our side with the sites list. It *should* eventually fix itself (the cache has a 48 hour time max on it), but it can be force fixed by logging out and back in or by clearing your data and logging back in.